# BULK insert/load using ADO / OLEDB

Tags: c++, sql, t-sql, ado

I am using ADO to access OLE DB server in my cpp code..

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    try {
        _ConnectionPtr ConnPtr;
        ConnPtr.CreateInstance("ADODB.Connection");
        ConnPtr.Open("Provider=ASEOLEDB; Data Source=MYSERVER; User ID=MYID; Password=MYPW");


        _RecordsetPtr RecPtr;
        RecPtr.CreateInstance("ADODB.Recordset");


        ReccPtr = Connptr.execute("BULK INSERT ...");
        // .................
        // ...bulk insert...
        // .................


        ConnPtr->Close();
    }
    catch (_com_error &e) {

    }
}
```

I can't find any resource online how to implement the bulk insert part.. I've read a post on bulk insert using Java, but I can't figure out how this could be done in C++/ADO..

(http://venzi.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/loading-data-fast-regular-insert-vs-bulk-insert/)

Does anyone have suggestions / resource on this topic?

Comment: Is regular insert fast enough?

Answer (score 0):

The BULK INSERT T-SQL statement imports data from a file.  The file needs to be stored locally on the SQL Server box or accessible via UNC path.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx.

To bulk insert directly from native code, you'll need to use the IRowsetFasLoad COM interface or ODBC_BCP function call.  Classic ADO does not have bulk insert method.  If managed code is an option, you can use the SqlClient SqlBulkCopy class.